# How do I know when the screen is being drawn on iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to know when the screen is being drawn on iOS.  In particular, I'd like to know if there are any visible changes being drawn on screen.  This can be handy to know how long a page took to render, for example (assuming that the user is not interacting with the page).  I would like to be able to capture this information in a regular production build, not in a developer build.  And I'd like this to be a general solution applicable to most any page in my app, not just a specific page.

For example, I have a page that 1) asynchronously queries an API for data, 2) displays that data in a UITableView where some of the entries may be offscreen, and then 3) asynchronously downloads the images for each of the visible items on the screen.  I want to get callbacks when the UITableView is rendered and when all of the images are rendered.  The total time to render the page can be determined by looking at the timestamp of the last call to the callback (again, assuming no user interaction).

On Android, this is fairly simple.  You can use [ViewTreeObserver.addPreDrawListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnPreDrawListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener)) to get a callback whenever the screen is being drawn.  If there's no visible change to the screen, the callback is not called.

On iOS, it looks like [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/index.html) might potentially serve a similar purpose.  However, when I hook up my CADisplayLink, it appears to be called over-and-over forever, whether or not there are visible changes on the screen.

Is there a way to know when there are visible changes to the screen being drawn in iOS?

Comment: The business of asynchronously populating a table view with downloaded material is extremely common and well solved (and well explained here on SO). I don't quite see what you need extra information for. The notion "the total time to render the page" is sort of meaningless because offscreen cells don't exist and are _not_ rendered.

Comment: I want to create a report that shows the 50th, 90th, and 95th percentiles of how long it takes users to load the page out in the real world so that I can get data that will help me optimize the page load performance of the app.

Comment: But then it is not the _drawing_ that you need to quantify, but the _downloading_. And that is something that is easily done. — And please, next time, ask the question to which you _really_ want to know the answer. You'll get better help and waste less time / bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks matt, I believe the question I asked is the one I want to know the answer to.  But I appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, I'm telling you that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 9 Apple made it impossible to get access to things drawn onto the screen outside of your app. Prior, it was possible to use an API called IOSurface to do it, but Apple closed it down in iOS 9. (To prevent apps from snooping on each other.)

So if you're talking about ANYTHING being drawn to the screen the answer is no. If you're looking for changes within your app there's probably a way to do it.

Comment: Good question.  I'm just looking for changes made to the screen from within the app.  Thanks!